# Would the lunar rovers work (again) today? What would be needed?

Tags: the-moon, reuse, lunar-rover, xprize

3 Apollo missions brought their lunar rovers ([Lunar Roving Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Roving_Vehicle)) LRV with them, and they remained on the moon.

Some of them have broken parts, and their batteries seem to be emtpy, according to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6268/21153).

However, **would they still be able to drive today, given new batteries?** Would a solar cell provide enough power to either load those batteries or allow to drive directly?

Background: I am wondering whether any of the current Lunar-X-Prize-Missions would be able to re-use those LRV's? Or is this ruled out by the competition anyways?

Comment: The electronics of the lunar rovers might be destroyed by the lunar environment with large temperature changes. The lubrication of bearings will be vaporized, if the rover is moved, cold weldings might be possible.