# Is it possible to build a rocket from EBay

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight

I want to write a young adults fiction book about a girl who buys an astronauts helmet from EBay and decides to see if she can then build a rocket to get to the moon. I'm a materials engineer, and with aircraft salvage yards and other resources I would think it is (just) within the realms of possibility if not probability, but obviously there are massive risk/barriers/etc. But, hypothetically, if you were to try it, what would you need. What would be the biggest hurdles, how you be creative to get around them.

Comment: [Astronaut Farmer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469263/) is a movie about a DIY astronaut. Not realistic of course. [Copenhagen Suborbitals](http://copenhagensuborbitals.com/) might also be of interest, and maybe microlaunchers. I think the complexity of space flight makes it too hard for it to work by improvizations with mixed second hand components. Even building a [toaster](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=build%20a%20toaster) from scratch is really hard.

Comment: Based on the comments & answers so far making a rocket is **difficult**. One line of attack for your story could be that a very capable girl starts designing a rocket & builds some components, someone from a rocket company or NASA sees her work, is very impressed, offers her a job & short tracks her career to being the commander of a lunar landing mission.

Comment: Also related: [Could I home-brew my own rocket fuel?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3805/415)

Comment: @Fred Except that the kind of people needed to engineer the spacecraft would be very different from the kind of people needed for the actual landing mission. You could plausibly get the main character fast-tracked up to some early test flights, but beyond that, I think it would be too much of a stretch to also put the same individual on a lunar landing mission.

Comment: Sally, they won't help you with *this particular* question, but you may also be interested in the [writers.se] and [worldbuilding.se] Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It wouldn't be feasible for a single person to achieve.  I'd add some level of fantasy to your book if you'd like to go with this plot; maybe she lives in a world with some sort of easily available extremely powerful and compact combustion device that is used in cars that she could bunch together to make a booster of some sorts?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly not, the time is against you.

It took the labour of 200,000 people several years to accomplish the Apollo lunar landing. If you were to do that all by yourself, it would take you pretty close to 1 million years. Even if you could live for that long, the part of the rocket you started with would have rusted away long ago when you are finished.

As people have pointed out in the comments, the Apollo program was far from bare bones, and a lot of those person-years was used on research. But even if you could cut down the time 500x, the argument still holds.

Comment: In all fairness, a lot of what went into the US moon landing program of the 1960s was research and development, which our protagonist could reap the benefits of without having to put in all the effort. While it would still take a very long time even given today's knowledge, I think simply counting man-years (person-years?) is oversimplifying it quite a bit. Then again, some things would be quite difficult to do alone, even given infinite time; I'm pretty sure handling a [F-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1) isn't something you'd want to do by yourself, for example.

Comment: I would think a more realistic cost would be that of, say, Crewed Dragon/ Falcon 9 heavy, which was more of a team of up to 10 thousand several years.

Comment: As a starting point, you might consider the time/cost to build a high-performance homebuilt aircraft, like the Lancair Evolution: http://www.flyingmag.com/aircraft/turboprops/lancair-evolution  Then consider that for a rocket, even if you could salvage all the parts needed to build it, you'd have a really major problem getting fuel.  Afout the only way to make it possible (in your fictional universe) is to invent some sort of anti-gravity or reactionless drive.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for a single person to make a moon mission.

The Apollo program is estimated to have taken somewhere around 15.5 billion man hours, even though some of the problems would be easier to solve now it would still take hundreds of millions of man hours (at least) to do it again. It takes engines providing millions of pounds of thrust, 7 million pounds of fuel and oxidizer, and vast amounts of specialized knowledge in hundreds of fields to make something like that work. None of that's on eBay.